# How to read a 3 int array to find middle and max numbers in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

If a user inputs [3, 5, 2]

How would I write a code so that it would correlate 3 to "a", 5 to "b", and 2 to "c"?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int a = input.nextInt();
    int b = input.nextInt();
    int c = input.nextInt();
    int x = 0;
    int t = 0;

    {
        //MIN
        x=a;
        if ((b < x))t=b;
        if ((c < x))x=c;

        //MAX
        t=a;
        if ((b > t)) t=b;
        if ((c > t)) t=c;
    }

    int m = a+b+c-x-t;
    System.out.print(m+t);
}
```

}

I'd like to not have separate int inputs for each variable, but one array.

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific. What exactly do you want? to find max value in array or to assign values to strings (3 to "a" ...)?

Comment: Assign values. I am very new with JAVA, forgive my lack of better terms and phrasing.

Comment: Can you post the whole task? I mean not only the problem part but everything your teacher wants you to do. That will help to find the best answer.

Comment: Well the question I asked isn't the exact assignment I have to do, it just an indirect part. I didn't want to ask directly, because I wanted to try to figure out. I think I'll just post the actual question next.

Comment: The first line of input contains a single integer specifying the number of data sets that follow. Each data set consists of three integers all on the same line with separating blanks. A data set may have repeated data (for instance the three integers might be 2 7 2 in which case, the smallest is 2, middle is 2, and largest is 7). There should be no prompts or legends. Compute the sum of the largest and middle for each data set and print it out on a separate line.

Comment: i edited my answer in a way to solve your task

Answer (score 1):

That should work fine:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    scanner.nextInt(); // this solution omits number of datasets. we don't really need it
    while (scanner.hasNext()) { // do we have one more line?
        list.clear(); // we need empty list
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++) { // read 3 numbers
            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        Collections.sort(list);
        Integer max = list.get(2);
        Integer middle = list.get(1);
        System.out.println(max+middle);
    }
```

Comment: I think using a `List` here might actually be overkill, as we know that there's always exactly three ints.  Just use an `int[]`.

Comment: It might be in this particular case. But in general using generic collections is easier and more safely. Resulting code is easier to read. I'm trying to use it wherever possible.

Comment: Generic collections are almost always best for collections of objects -- but for fixed-size lists of primitives, honestly, collections are still overkill.  They really don't add any more safety, but they do cost speed, and if you want to interface with generic collection tools, you can use something like Guava's [`Ints.asList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)).